# SQL - How to remove repeating values

Tags: sql, sql-server

My requirement is to remove the repeating values.

```
id  name    surname value
1   Vinduja Vijayan 5
3   Vinduja Vijayan 6
4   Vinduja Vijayan 7
```

Required output:

```
id  name    surname value
1   Vinduja Vijayan 5
3   NuLL    Null    6
4   NULL    NULL    7
```

Comment: While it _can_ be done with modern SQL, this is still better handled in your application

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2012

Comment: Can you help me with modern sql  .I need query .I am not making any application @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: What if two people with the same name appear?

Comment: Seems an odd requirement, if there is more than one distinct name wont most rows be unrelatable/meaningless?

Comment: name and surname are appearing 3 times .I want combination of name and surname appear only once ,when same name and surname combination come 2nd times ,null value should be passed @RossBush

Answer (score 3):

This transformation should usually be applied in the application layer.  It is possible to do in SQL, but not recommended, by using `row_number()` and `case`:

```
select id,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by name, surname order by id) = 1
             then name
        end) as name,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by name, surname order by id) = 1
             then surname
        end) as surname
from t
order by id;
```

Note that the final `order by` is very, very important.  SQL result sets (like tables) are *unordered* by default.  Without an explicit `order by`, the results could be in any order, and that would mess up your interpretation of the results.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (
        Id INT
        ,Name VARCHAR(20)
        ,Surname VARCHAR(20)
        ,value INT
        );


INSERT into @table(ID,Name,Surname,value)
Select 1,'Vinduja','Vijayan',5
Union
Select 3,'Vinduja','Vijayan',6
Union
Select 4,'Vinduja','Vijayan',7

Select S.Id ,T.Name,T.Surname,S.value from (
Select * ,ROW_NUMBER() Over(Partition by name Order by name) [Row]
From @table)S 
Left join @table T On T.Id =S.Id and S.[Row]=1
```

Comment: That doesn't work - try it with the same first name, but different surnames

Comment: it will work because condition is apply on the first Name not on the surname

Answer (score 1):

```
select
id,
case when rnk=1 then name end as name,
case when rnk=1 then surname end as surname ,
value
from
(
select
id,name,surname,value,
row_number()over(partition by name,surname order by id) as rnk
from table_name)repeatname
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your requirements. If you just want to display the data as described, then this won't work. But if you're trying to change the data in your table, this will do that.

```
DECLARE @Dupes TABLE
(
  id INT
  ,name VARCHAR(30)
  ,surname VARCHAR(30)
  ,value INT
);

INSERT @Dupes
  (
    id
   ,name
   ,surname
   ,value
  )
VALUES
  (1, 'Vinduja', 'Vijayan', 5),
  (3, 'Vinduja', 'Vijayan', 6),
  (4, 'Vinduja', 'Vijayan', 7);

WITH cte AS 
(
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [name], surname ORDER BY id) AS RowNum
    ,id
    ,name
    ,surname
    ,value
  FROM @Dupes
)
UPDATE cte
  SET cte.name = NULL
      ,cte.surname = NULL
  WHERE 
    cte.RowNum > 1;

SELECT *
FROM @Dupes;

--Results
+----+---------+---------+-------+
| id |  name   | surname | value |
+----+---------+---------+-------+
|  1 | Vinduja | Vijayan |     5 |
|  3 | NULL    | NULL    |     6 |
|  4 | NULL    | NULL    |     7 |
+----+---------+---------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

And just for interest, using the `LAG` function. I assumed SQL Server.

```
select id, 
       iif(name = previous_name, null, name) name, 
       iif(surname = previous_surname, null, surname) surname
  from (
    select name, surname, id, 
           lag(name, 1, null) over (order by name, surname, id) previous_name, 
           lag(surname, 1, null) over (order by name, surname, id) previous_surname
      from table_name ) a
 order by a.name, a.surname, a.id
```